# ATG CSC Environment exception

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

for one of our site while clicking on Workonlink in ordersearch reults i am getting below excption:

```
Error /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-55/atg/commerce/custsvc/environment/ChangeOrder --- atg.svc.agent.environment.EnvironmentException: Order contains unsupported features and cannot be modified.
Error /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-142/atg/commerce/custsvc/environment/ChangeOrder at atg.commerce.csr.environment.UIEnvironmentMonitor.generateDependentDetailsForOrderChange(UIEnvironmentMonitor.java:171)
Error Mon Jun 01 18:39:53 EST 2015 1433147993695 /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-/atg/commerce/custsvc/environment/ChangeOrder at atg.commerce.csr.environment.UIEnvironmentMonitor.generateDependentChangeDetails(UIEnvironmentMonitor.java:144)
Error /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-142/atg/commerce/custsvc/environment/ChangeOrder at atg.svc.agent.environment.EnvironmentMonitor.generateChangeDetails(EnvironmentMonitor.java:179)..
```

can anyone please tell how enviornment things work in csc.

Thanks..

Comment: Please have a tour to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using some b2b features which are not supported in CSC.  Below is an extract from the Oracle ATG documentation:

> Note: Commerce Service Center does not support Commerce B2B features within orders. If the order contains a B2B feature, such as a purchase order or cost centers, you will be able to view the order, but will be unable to make any modifications to the order. An error message will appear, indicating that the order contains unsupported features and cannot be modified.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Service.10-2/ATGCommerceServiceCenterUserGuide/html/s0408modifyingexistingorders01.html)